# Calculating data bytes in node js

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I have a vhd (disk) of size 500 MB, of which only 10 MB of data is written, followed by empty chunks and finally one more block of 10 MB towards the end.

So , the total data present is just 20 MB out of 500 MB.
I am trying to find a utility in node.js , to find out the number of data bytes, not succeeded though.

There is a function **fs.fstatSync(file).size**, which gives the total size.

Is there any utility/functions to calculate the data written?

Comment: If you're using a fixed VHD, there's no easy way to calculate that except to parse the partition table and maybe some filesystem structures.

Comment: Yes, I am using a fixed vhd only .   any reference to any of the articles/blogs available to start off with?I am very new to node.js, in .net there is ready apis available for this ?

Comment: You could spawn a child process to run a shellscript. Other that that, I don't think node has a way to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use [`require("child_process")`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to access some system utility cli.